# How to create random color to fill a circle? Running Python in bash terminal mac

Tags: python, python-3.4, geometry

the equation for my circle is

```
 circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5, color ="r", alpha=0.75)
```

here, the r represents red however I'm wondering if its possible to fill the circle with a random color.

I've tried (after importing random)

```
 COLORS = [(139, 0, 0), 
          (0, 100, 0),
          (0, 0, 139)] 
 circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5, color='random.choice(COLORS)', alpha=0.75)
```

and I have tried

```
 nums = map(lambda x : random.randint(0,7), range(50))
 cols = map(lambda i: colour[i], nums)
 circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5, color='cols', alpha=0.75)
```

Comment: Why are you quoting expressions? I think it should be `random.choice(COLORS)`, not `'random.choice(COLORS)'`.

Comment: What's the output/error you get? What's the array ```colour``` in ```colour[i]```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate you a random color in Hex format

```
import random

def component():
  return random.randint(0,255)

col = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (component(),component(),component())
circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5, color=col, alpha=0.75)
```

or short version:

```
component = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5, color='#%02X%02X%02X' % (component(),component(),component()), alpha=0.75)
```